# How to work on two copies of the same image side by side without one effecting the other in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I managed to open the same image twice side by side with the help of this question [Open two copies of the same file side-by-side in Photoshop](https://superuser.com/questions/248616/open-two-copies-of-the-same-file-side-by-side-in-photoshop)
 but the problem is that whatever work I do on one copy of my image it gets reflected to the other. Which I don't want. I just want to see how each copy of my image looks when on different effect. So how can I achieve that?

Please note that I am new to Photoshop so I don't know much about it.

Comment: I guess you could convert the layer(s) in the document to a [Smart Object](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/create-smart-objects.html). You do the edits inside the original document and open up the smart object contents to see how the original image looked. Embedded smart object lives inside the psd file... Otherwise it's exactly the same as duplicating the document.

Comment: Why did my question got downvoted ? Can I know the reason so that I can fix it... Also I mentioned in the question that I am new to Photoshop...

Comment: @Joonas I think you misunderstood my question. I said **I just want to see how each copy of my image looks when on different effect** so I am not keeping the original image both images will have a different look. (Non will be like original)

Comment: Right, I kinda just assumed you wanted to compare one effect at a time against the original.... But do you mean that with the current solution you duplicate the original document and then add a new effect, so that you will have one document for each effect + the original? And if you have 20 effects, you want to view all of them at the same time + the original?

Comment: @Joonas In my example i just wanted to have just two same images side by side not more than that... and each would have a different effect and don't need to open the original file.

Comment: The funny thing is... The more you say, the more confusing it gets for me. Your last sentence... How do you view the version with the effect and the original at the same time if you don't open the original file? — Anyways... If it truly is two images side by side, then I don't know why the smart object thing wouldn't work. The only real difference between a duplicate document file and the smart object (in this case), is that the smart object lives inside the psd file. [Here's an example](https://youtu.be/1taSOi64a38).

Comment: If I had saved the `Untitled 1` in the video as psd, that `Layer 1` smart object would've been saved with it. The only thing this changes is that you don't have to juggle 2 separate files in your hard drive since the original is saved in that one `.psd`. This is a little off-topic, but smart objects are often used not necessarily so much for comparing images side by side, but for storing the original image so that you can make edits without destroying the source image. Even if I just want to resize an image, I often make it into a SO so that I retain the original size... just in case.

Answer (score 2):

You need **two separate hard drive files** to do what you are trying to do.

The "New View" item in Photoshop is just that - a **view** -  not a different file. It merely allows you to see the *same file* at a different zoom level. It does not create a separately editable file.  You need multiple hard drive files all opened at the same time if you wish to make different edits.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... how is my solution ? and where is this `New View` option located in Photoshop ?

Comment: You basically just **created a second file on the hard drive**, which is what I stated. There's no problem with that, but be careful you don't start randomly duplicating files and losing track of viable edits.

Comment: I did not saw your answer until I found the solution... but anyways thanks for the knowledge....

Comment: Why was my question downvoted ? Can I know the reason ? So that I can try to fix it..

Comment: I have no clue. I didn't down vote anything.

Comment: Okay thanks for the reply though...

Answer (score 0):

**I found the solution and here is it:**

*Note: below steps are for Photoshop cs 6*

1. Open the image in Photoshop and goto `Windows > Arrange > Float in window`. (or just double click on the title of the image and while holding the mouse move it up or down )
2. Right click on the title bar of the image and click on Duplicate.
3. Then again goto `Windows > Arrange > Float in window`.
4. Now goto `Windows > Arrange > 2-up Vertical`. And you are done.

Thanks. :)

Comment: Note that this is then working on **2 separate files** not the "same image". Check the hard drive, there's now a duplicate file next to the original file.